# Fixing url spaces using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to use only CSS to fix url spaces?

Eg: A couple of my url's go like this

```
<p class="Small-Brown-No-Italic">Link Here: <a href="http://www.example.com/static/TextBox.html  "><span class="Hyperlink _idGenCharOverride-1">http://www.example.com/static/TextBox.html</span></a></p>
```

Notice the space in the href attribute towards the end. When the user clicks on this url, it gets converted to:

```
http://www.example.com/static/TextBox.html%20%20
```

Can CSS help here to fix the spacing issues towards the end of the url? I cannot use JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the spaces?

Comment: No, CSS can't do anything about that. Why can't you use JavaScript? Or better yet, fix whatever is adding spaces?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no, CSS cannot do anything to that.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming. I cannot remove it manually as there are hundreds of similar links to be fixed

Comment: @user1089173 So just add some Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this using CSS, you'll need to use, e.g. Javascript*:

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;links.length;i++){
    links[i].setAttribute('href',links[i].getAttribute('href').trim());
}
```

Remember the seperation of concerns, and responsibility- i.e HTML is for *content*, CSS for *styling* and JS for *functionality*.

<sup>* indictative only</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You must correct your URLs before sending them.

If you have a lot of URL with this problem, just loop over them and apply `trim()` (PHP) per exemple.